# Brackets plugins not working in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, plugins, adobe-brackets

I am running brackets v14 and the plugin manager is not loading after a fresh install of brackets (through the software center).

In the debug tools I am seeing the following error:

```
NodeConnection.js:84 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:37055/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any ideas on how to debug this?
(in the software center I see many reports with regards to the plugins not working, but no solution so far)

My node version is: 10.15.2

Comment: This is a known issue of Brackets. you should take it up with his developer https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/13730 there is a quick fix though : you can change the language under "debug" from "system default" to "English(US)". Is there any particular reason you choose this app? there is no real market for it? it is not lighter nor more feature packed than Atom or other options. it's the runt of the litter.

Comment: It solves the plugin manager from opening (great tip), but unfortunately using (manually installed) or installing plugins still does not work.

Comment: if your problem changed that's a new question then. not on this forum though. you must report the bug to bracket's developer. I'm not bracket's developer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of Brackets. you should take it up with his developer:

https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/13730

There is a quick fix though : you can change the language under "debug" from "system default" to "English(US)".